# Fk relationships in Entities

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

I know this is a very basic question.
I have two tables

Project - ID, Name ,TypeID
ProjectType - ID,Name

In MVC I have a controller action to create a new project. When creating the project I assign the Type of the project before passing it to the view as below

```
//
        // GET: /Project/Create

        public ActionResult Create(string id= null)
        {

            ProjectType selprojtype = null;
            if (id != null)
            {
                selprojtype = db.ProjectTypes.Include("Projects").Single(p => p.Name == id);
          }

            Project project = new Project();
            project.ProjectType = selprojtype;
            //project.TypeID = selprojtype.ID;  -
            var model = new ProjectViewModel(project);
            PopulateDropDownLists(model);
            return View(model);
        }
```

My question is doing the following only associates the ProjectType object.

```
Project project = new Project();
 project.ProjectType = selprojtype;
```

The TypeID on the project still remains null.Unless i do this

```
 project.TypeID = selprojtype.ID;
```

Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

I would not store the `TypeID` on the `Project` class since this value is already on the `ProjectType` class.  If you need to access this value, you can do it like this:

```
project.ProjectType.ID
```

If you need to access the ID directly from the `Project` class, you can create a pass-through property. E.g.

```
public class Project
{
    public ProjectType ProjectType { get; set; }
    public int TypeID
    {
        get { return ProjectType.ID; }
    }
}
```

Comment: I am using Reverse Engineer to create the classes from my database. how do you prevent the property from being exposed?

Comment: Does your database specify a relationship between Project and ProjectType? (i.e. right-click table in Management Studio - design. Right-click in design view - Relationships)

Comment: `Project` is an entity and removing a foreign key property from an entity has deep implications (you change a foreign key association to an independent association). I wouldn't recommend this step just for the purpose of saving this single line of code in the question.

Comment: @Slauma, Removing the `TypeID` from the class would not remove the foreign key in the database.  The foreign key would still be referenced through the `ProjectType` property. That is generally how ORMs (like Entity Framework) implement foreign keys.

Comment: You misunderstood. EF has two different ways to handle associations internally and it affects the way you have to deal with relationships between entities; it has nothing to do with the DB layout. "Independent associations" are more difficult to master than "foreign key associations" (google for the keywords) in many scenarios and this is what your proposal would change. Just saying, your proposal works and looks clean but it has a lot more consequences than it might seem to have.

Comment: @Kevin yes my database has a relationship between Project and ProjectType

Comment: I was not able to see a way to remove the property from being created once the model has already been generated. When generating a new model, uncheck the "Include foreign key columns in the model" option in the wizard.  Perhaps someone more knowledgeable in EF can comment and provide better guidance.  Also, please take note of Slauma's comment above.

Answer (score 0):

Nope : )

Have your constructor for ProjectViewModel() read it from the passed in Project instance and set the id by reading it from the project.ProjectType